# passing document data to the view controllers in yosemite (storyboards)

Tags: swift, storyboard, osx-yosemite, nsdocument

When are you supposed to pass your document or document data to your viewcontrollers? It can not be done in prepareForSegue because this function is not called for view controllers that are part of a containment/relationship seque.

Also not in windowControllerDidLoadNib because this is not always called either.

Comment: It's a conceptual question. The question applies even if you start from a new Document based project with just 1 viewController. It's a question that pertains to the life cycle of the views and the document. Code is always not required in every question.



But since you insist: where do you put this line? windowController.contentViewController?.representedObject = self (i.e. document)

Comment: I am curious how it can be done as I am also hitting on this brick wall. There seems to be a way to referencing the object but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current approach is this:

1. Subclass NSDocument and override makeWindowControllers to pass the document instance to the window controller.
2. Subclass NSWindowController and override windowDidLoad to pass the document (or any other type of data) to the contentViewController.
3. Subclass the NSViewController to handle the data and/or pass it along to childViewControllers.
4. Use notifications to notify NSViewControllers if something (like the selection) has changed in another NSViewController.

Comment: It seems like setDocument is not a member of NSWindowController and I am not able to override it. Most examples I found were in Objective-C and they all overrode setDocument. Also there seems no setFileString in NSDocument. Can you please share your Swift code here? Thanks.

Comment: You don't use setDocument. NSWindowController has a "var document: AnyObject?". So you would do aWindowController.document = self (or yourDocument instance)

Comment: windowDidLoad was called when I initialized windowController before I could pass document into it. What could have I missed?

override func makeWindowControllers() {
      // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
      let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let windowController: DocumentWindowController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Document Window Controller") as! DocumentWindowController
      
      self.addWindowController(windowController)
      windowController.document = self
   }

Comment: That code is correct. You can use windowWillAppear to load data from your document, or you can add a didSet to your document variable.

Comment: Is there windowWillAppear in NSWindowController? Do you mean by overriding "var document: AnyObject? { didSet..."?

Comment: forgot to say, I set the representedObject of the contentViewController of the main window controller to the document.

Comment: Actually, it is to set the representedObject in override funs viewWillAppear of NSViewController subclass.